# TypeCast operator Exception being thrown in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm getting some unexpected behaviour from a TypeCast conversion in C#..

When trying to convert..

```
float f = 123124334234234.34F;
```

into an Integer as follows:

```
int i = (int)f;
```

I'm getting an Exception thrown. According to MSDN "In general, implicit conversion operators should never throw exceptions and never lose information so that they can be used safely without the programmer's awareness.".

Also, according to this guy at the 7:54 mark in the video, he states and shows an example where a typecast operator is used for a conversion does not throw an Exception.

video link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcDaNmGDMoM&index=8&list=PLAC325451207E3105

So why an I getting an OverflowException when I run the above code?

Comment: That's the actual code. It's not supposed to be throwing an Exception..

Comment: the value you want to convert is higher than MAXVALUE for an int - try a long

Comment: Even though it's larger, it shouldn't throw exception.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes, that's what the guy in the video was getting as well. The MIN_VALUE for Int I believe. I'm just getting an OverflowException.

Comment: I get an OverflowException that points to the exact line that does the cast.

Comment: I'm doing this in SharpDevelop.. I wonder if that's related somehow? The video is done in VisualStudio and if I were to have to guess @GrantWinney, I would guess you got Int32.MinValue as a result in Visual Studio as well..

Comment: Are you running this against the _Mono_ framework/runtime or the Microsoft .NET runtime?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I don't believe I even have the Mono framework installed and SharpDevelop consistently refers to the .NET framework.

Comment: Any chance you have the [`/checked+`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx) compiler flag set? I'm not positive, but maybe this is what's causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, SharpDevelop enables the "Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow" flag, which Visual Studio has *disabled* by default.

You can disable it in the project properties:

[image]

Similarly, if anyone stumbles on this post and is using Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you may have the [`/checked+`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx) compiler flag set. With that switched on, arithmetic operations that would normally overflow instead throw exceptions at run-time.

> If an integer arithmetic statement that is not in the scope of a
>   checked or unchecked keyword results in a value outside the range of
>   the data type, and /checked+ (/checked) is used in the compilation,
>   that statement causes an exception at run time.

With the following code:

```
float f = 123124334234234.34F;
int i = (int)f;
```

With the setting turned off, it overflows to a negative number normally. With the flag switched on, it throws the overflow exception instead.

EDIT: That said, I don't know how to change that flag in SharpDevelop. Instructions for Visual Studio are included in the linked page above; perhaps they are similar for SharpDevelop.

Comment: Excellent observation. I'll try changing the flag later and see if that changes the behaviour.

Comment: Yup, that's the solution. Project > Project Options > 'Compiling' Tab. There is an option in the 'General' list that is called 'Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow'. It was checked. Unchecked, the code does not throw an Exception and returns Int32.MinValue.

Comment: Sorry to remove the check, but you pointed out the path and the answer below lit it up. Thanks for your excellent contribution and thoughts!